# csv file extracting by example in powerquery

Tags: csv, powerquery

I am extracting the CSV data through by PowerQuery by giving an Example shown in the picture below;

I would like to do it through PowerQuery M language, or by python could anyone help with this?

[image]

```
ProductKey  OrderDateKey    DueDateKey  ShipDateKey CustomerKey PromotionKey    CurrencyKey SalesTerritoryKey   SalesOrderNumber    SalesOrderLineNumber    RevisionNumber  OrderQuantity   UnitPrice   ExtendedAmount  UnitPriceDiscountPct    DiscountAmount  ProductStandardCost TotalProductCost    SalesAmount TaxAmt  Freight CarrierTrackingNumber   CustomerPONumber    OrderDate   DueDate ShipDate
535 20140101    20140113    20140108    11051   1   100 9   SO74253 1   1   1   24.99   24.99   0   0   9.3463  9.3463  24.99   1.9992  0.6248          1/01/2014 0:00  13/01/2014 0:00 8/01/2014 0:00
528 20140101    20140113    20140108    11051   1   100 9   SO74253 2   1   1   4.99    4.99    0   0   1.8663  1.8663  4.99    0.3992  0.1248          1/01/2014 0:00  13/01/2014 0:00 8/01/2014 0:00
222 20140101    20140113    20140108    11051   1   100 9   SO74253 3   1   1   34.99   34.99   0   0   13.0863 13.0863 34.99   2.7992  0.8748          1/01/2014 0:00  13/01/2014 0:00 8/01/2014 0:00
```

Comment: But M is exactly what Power Query is using. When you're done querying by example, you can retrieve the query through "Transform Data" and then the advanced editor. M itself is not interactive and it has no functionality for importing files through examples; there's only `Csv.Document` that you have to parameterize yourself.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you mean to use formulas like Table Rows to Columns? If there is sth like...But my trouble is while I am importing file csv, it imports all columns  in one column. And I cannot widen the result by delimiter comma

Comment: Ah, I see, the problem is that the file for some reason decides to quote the entire line, instead of individual columns, which is weird. If there are no "real" quotes in the file anywhere, you can work around this by replacing them first. Something like `Csv.Document(Text.Replace(Text.FromBinary(File.Contents("<path to file>")), "#(0022)", ""))`. If there *are* real quotes in there mixed in with the start and end it gets more annoying.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Hey that worked. Could you please give more detailed explanation. As I understand (0022) is carriage line? but what des the other part of the formula. It worked by the way

Comment: No, `#(0022)` is the M escape syntax for the quote character, so this just removes all quotes from the text before feeding it to `Csv.Document`. For the case where the lines themselves do contain quotes, it would be `Csv.Document(Text.Combine(List.Transform(Lines.FromText(Text.FromBinary(File.Contents(..))), each Text.Trim(_, "#(0022)")), "#(cr)#(lf)"))`, where we split lines, remove the quotes and put them back together again. Obviously this reads better if split up into multiple steps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
let
    Lines = Lines.FromBinary(File.Contents("<path>")),
    UnquoteLines = List.Transform(Lines, each Text.Trim(_, "#(0022)")),
    CombinedLines = Text.Combine(UnquoteLines, "#(cr)#(lf)"),
    Source = Csv.Document(CombinedLines)
in
    Source
```

This removes the beginning and ending quotes from each line before combining them again and sending them off to `Csv.Document`. Splitting the steps this way retains compatibility with the query settings editor for the first and last step (for example, if you need to change the encoding, or the CSV delimiter).